# Assign variable as key name ordereddict

Tags: python

How can I assign a `variable` as a `key name` in `OrderedDict`.

In the example below, I am trying to assign `SecondName` from `OrderedDict` as a `keyname`:

```
for i in list:
  newod = OrderedDict(name=i['firstname'], i['Secondname']=i['Marks']))
```

If I do the above for assigning the `i['Secondname]` as a `key name`, I get an error `Cant assign to function call`.

How can I make this work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary and spread it with the `**` operator:

```
for i in list:
  newod = OrderedDict(name=i['firstname'], **{i['Secondname']: i['Marks']})
```

Comment: I am not sure if that will preserve the order though